# How to open two terminals using python subprocess package and provide some input/commands in both the terminals

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to open two terminals and provide some commands in both the terminals.
Now I am not able to provide any input in any of the terminals.
process.stdin.write() is not working in any of the terminal
Please help me out.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["start", "cmd", "/k", r'ipconfig'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["start", "cmd", "/k", "dir"], stdin=p.stdout,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
p.stdin.write("dir")
p1.stdin.write("ipconfig")
p.stdout.close()
output = p1.communicate()[0]
print(output)
print(p1.stdout)
```

I have tried creationflags like detached process and create new console.
but it is not working

Comment: Why don't you use `subprocess.check_output` function. It requires a list of command tokens then it executes them and waits for the output which it returns as bytes. Then you just decode the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.check_output(["ipconfig"], shell=True).decode("utf-8")
p1 = subprocess.check_output(["dir"], shell=True).decode("utf-8")
print(p, p1, sep="\n\n")
```

Note that the returned output is of type `bytes` so it has to be decoded to a string with an encoding. I've chosen *UTF-8* which is a popular encoding.